# Add a big buffer to a pipe between two commands

Tags: bash, unix

Given a bash command line of the form

```
commandA | commandB
```

I want to add a buffer of size ~1MB that sits between `commandA` and `commandB`.
I would expect to be able to do this with something of the form

```
commandA | BUFFER | commandB
```

but what is the command to use for `BUFFER`?

Remark: I want to do this in order to decouple the two commands to make them parallelize better. The problem is that `commandB` processes data in large chunks, which currently means that `commandA` blocks until `commandB` is done with a chunk. So everything runs sequentially :-(

Answer (score 30, accepted):

BUFFER is called buffer. (man 1 buffer, maybe after apt-get install buffer)

Comment: What are the options one should pass to buffer to get a, eg. 1Gb buffer size ? There seem to be many options to configure chunk size, number of chunks and whatever, but it is not clear to me which ones to use to get a simple buffer of a given size.

Comment: `-m size` is for the total. If you need finer-grained control use `-s blocksize -b blocks` together.

Answer (score 26):

There is another tool, [`pv`](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) - pipe viewer:

```
process1 | pv -pterbTCB 1G | process2
```

- `B` specifies the buffer size, here 1 Gigibyte
- `C` disables `splice`, which is required for `B`
- `T` shows the buffer level
- `pterb` are the default display switches needed due to the presence of `T`

`pv` might be available on systems where `mbuffer/buffer` is not in the official repositories (such as `arch linux`).

Comment: I tried using `pv` as buffer, but it sometimes stops reading its input when its output blocks while the buffer is not full. It appears to be a bug, as attaching with `strace` fixes it. `pv` with a buffer also switches between reading and writing every 100 ms or until no more data is ready, but that slowed down reading from disk when I tried it. I guess the 100 ms gap was too long for the system to continue reading ahead.

Comment: -pterbTCB 1G  are great default opts . should be in the man page!

Answer (score 8):

You can use

- buffer (mentioned)
- mbuffer (works on solaris too, possibly other UNIXes)

E.g.

```
    process1 | mbuffer -m 1024M | process2
```

to use a 1G buffer

Comment: mbuffer seems much better than buffer since buffer is (according to manpage and my experiments) limited to 1GB.

Answer (score 4):

The program `buffer` uses shared memory. This might be a problem, because in case of an error, memory may leak, because shared memory can outlive the program, which allocated the memory.

An alternative may be GNU `dd`:

```
commandA |
dd status=none iflag=fullblock bs=1M |
commandB
```

It is important to use the `fullblock` option. Otherwise `dd` may cause data loss, when reading from a pipe.

**Parameters of `dd` explained**

- status=none

  Set the  level of information to print to stderr; 'none' suppresses everything but error messages
- iflag=fullblock

  accumulate full blocks of input
- bs=1M

  read and write up to one Mega bytes at a time (default: 512 bytes);

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called `stdbuf` that lets you specify the buffer size of the pipe, something like:

```
stdbuf -o 1M commandA | commandB
```

Answer (score -4):

alternatively you could use a named pipe and run them in parallel:

```
mkfifo myfifo
commandB < myfifo &
commandA > myfifo
rm myfifo
```

Comment: That buffers about 64KB only - not big.

Comment: This solution has the same buffer size as `commandA | commandB`.