# Is it possible to limit the number of lines in a linux pipeline?

Tags: pipe

I have a bash pipeline. I would like to stop too much work being by the earlier workers before the later workers have processed it. Is there a way to decrease the amount data that can be stored in a pipe and I can I specify this limit in lines rather than bytes?

I'm aware that the "correct" way of doing this would be to use a message passing system -but that seems like a bunch of overhead.

Comment: That's up to the individual programs to configure for themselves, IIRC. They'll be given data as often as they ask for it

Comment: Once the buffer fills up, the pipeline should block, right? Are you seeing a problem, or just thinking ahead to one that may not exist? If you are really concerned, does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51636391/how-to-set-pipe-size-from-shell help?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can with the pv utility and the -l switch.
For example:

```
$dmesg |pv -qL 1 -l
```

will display kernel info one line per second.

```
$cat my_file.txt | pv -L 5 -l | some_program
```

will send the contents of my `my_file.txt` through `pv` and `pv` will pass it to some_program at the selected rate.
Without the `-q` switch you get a progress bar corresponding the data being send through the pipe. Without `-l` the parameter is taken as bytes per second. More details on the manual `man pv`

Install it through your package manager pv.

Ubuntu: `apt install pv`

OpenSuse: `zypper in pv`

etc.