Can a Python program find orphan processes that it previously created?
I'm using popen() to create potentially long-running processes in Python.  If the parent program dies and then restarts, is there a way to retrieve the previously created processes that are still running?  I'd probably have to use start_new_session=True, which I'm not doing now.
Essentially, I want to get a re-constructed instance of a popen object that points to the child process.  I suspect it's not possible, since serializing a popen() object doesn't seem to be possible.

You could save the process IDs in a file. Then when you restart, you can check whether those process IDs are still running.

But if your goal is to reattach the process so you can read its output, that's not possible.

...though even if they are still running they won't be children after a restart, so you can't wait() for them &c. I'd probably want to put a different abstraction in play if you want to be able to have child processes that outlive their parent -- like using systemd-run to create transitive services, such that one can then query systemd for output/status/&c.

Agree with everything said above. However you can obviously still communicate using standard i/o streams.

@TeejayBruno, not for an anonymous pipe (as created by popen) where the parent process side was attached to a process that exited. At that point reads/writes on the far side will be getting EPIPE errors, if the process wasn't killed by a SIGPIPE earlier when the parent failed.

(ergh, meant "transient" services above)

First of all, if one of the processes connected with a pipe dies, any read/write from/to that pipe will result in SIGPIPE -- which by default terminates the process. So your orphan process is very likely to die promptly, too, if the parent crashes.

As per Can I share a file descriptor to another process on linux or are they local to the process?, it's only possible to share a file discriptor between unrelated processes via a UNIX domain socket, and that requires active participation from both processes.
As others have pointed out, you also won't be able to wait for that process.

Depending on what you're trying to achieve (e.g. it's a worker process and you don't want to lose its progress), a better way may be to e.g. save the progress at some points (whether by the parent or by the child) and add an ability to restart from a saved state.

Yes, you're last point.  I don't want to lose it's progress and want to be able to continue reading it's stdout.  But it sounds like that's might not be possible.

@PeterKronenberg You can take a look at a dedicated stream buffering program like pv: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554568/add-a-big-buffer-to-a-pipe-between-two-commands (not sure if it has a reconnection feature). Also probably can use FIFO files rather than pipes. IIRC you can freely reconnect to a FIFO file from any process. Or, you know, just use regular files...

@PeterKronenberg Of course, there's the issue why the parent process crashes in the first place. Reading a stream doesn't seem to be such a complicated task as to cause unpredictable and unpreventable crashes. Maybe it'd be more productive to rather fix that.

It's a server that is kicking off multiple processes.  A million reasons a server might crash that have nothing to do with its child processes.   The server might also need to be bounced for unrelated reasons.  Just trying to be proactive
